# Cosmos DB out of Memory exception while executing stored procedure

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using Azure Cosmos DB SQL API . I have written stored procedure will get the data and keeps in response API feed .

> Failed to execute stored procedure testProcedure for collection
>   iotcollection:
>   {"code":400,"body":"{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"Message:
>   {\\"Errors\\":[\\"Encountered exception while executing function.
>   Exception = Error: Out of memory\\r\\nStack trace:
>   undefined\\"]}\r\nActivityId: c286cbb6-34c1-4929-a148-915544b20ce6,
>   Request URI:
>   /apps/59d3b9ef-17ca-4bbf-8a11-39d0199a8d29/services/1b26e00f-1f51-4d34-88ec-4090b8e7db00/partitions/45a313b7-2cf2-419e-9885-48bf9cfe6277/replicas/131862936473830809p/,
>   RequestStats: \r\nRequestStartTime: 2018-11-10T05:46:36.4852333Z,
>   Number of regions attempted: 1\r\n, SDK:
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.1.0.0\"}","activityId":"c286cbb6-34c1-4929-a148-915544b20ce6"}

My stored procedure is very simple one I just wanted to see how many records i can fetch from cosmos DB at given time and send as response.

```
    // SAMPLE STORED PROCEDURE
function sample(prefix) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT r.data FROM root r',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
        // else take 1st element from feed
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            var body = { prefix: prefix, feed: feed[0] };
            var str = 'str';
            for ( var i =0 ; i < 100 ; i = i +1 ){
                    str = str + str ;
                    body .str = feed[0];
            }

            response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Cosomos DB stored procedure response size too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53180181/azure-cosomos-db-stored-procedure-response-size-too-large)

Comment: Hi,Amjath,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the reason of `Out-Of-Memory`error is the `str` string is too long during your loop. It seems that the `str` string is useless for your test which is not added into response.

Please remove it and the sample stored procedure will work fine.